# VBA COUNTIFS double criteria match statement

Tags: vba, countif

I'm trying to count based on two criteria conditions being met using COUNTIFS.  I can get it to work Im using one criteria but when I use two it throws an error "Expected: end of statement.

```
myworksheet.Cells(1, "A") = "HIGH"
myworksheet.Cells(1, "B") = "=COUNTIFS(" & otherworksheet.Name & "!A2:A" & LastRow & ",A1, & otherworksheet.Name & "B2:B" & LastRow & ","*bingo*")"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you got mixed up in all the quotation marks.

```
myworksheet.Cells(1, "B") = "=COUNTIFS(" & otherworksheet.Name & "!A2:A" & LastRow & ",A1," & otherworksheet.Name & "!B2:B" & LastRow & ",""*bingo*"")"
```

Added closing quotation marks after

```
",A1,
```

Also, to send quotation marks to excel, use double quotation marks. Like this:

```
",""*bingo*"")"
```

Also added ! here:

```
otherworksheet.Name & "!B2:B"
```

---

Also, if you are gonna use the cells command, why not use it with proper coordinates? Or why don't you just use the range command?

```
Cells(1, 1)
```

or

```
Range("A1")
```